# Pushing and new heads in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, push

I'd like to see what exactly would be created during a push, if I get the `abort: push creates new remote heads!` error. How can I check that?

Some more details: I'm pulling from one repository (upstream) and pushing to a local fork which does have additional branches, but already contains all upstream ones. Also, I'm only pushing one upstream branch.

When I look at `hg outgoing <fork_repo>`, I see a stream of commits with a parent and then some commits without. I'm not sure how to understand that really.

Comment: don't do it, always merge before pushing otherwise you will get a huge mess ... hg does not work well with multiple branches on the same repo

Comment: Well - that's exactly what I want to have - multiple branches. The problem is that I have branches A and B in local repo and A, B, C in the remote one - I don't see how that could add a new head (there are no commits in local repo that would have to be merged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to run `hg pull`.  That way, your local repository will contain exactly what the remote repository will contain after the push.

If you don't want to pull, combining `hg incoming` and `hg outgoing` will usually give you enough information to see which are the two heads.

Comment: I added some information about what I'm doing to the question. It's pretty bizarre to me how can I have only one head in a branch in the local repo, but it could create multiple ones in the remote one.